# How to remove databinding of a single attribute of an element dynamically?

Tags: polymer

I need to remove databinding dynamically in my javascript

### From

```
<my-element-a id="elem_a" label="{{ mylabel }}" value="{{ myvalue }}"></my-element>  
<my-element-b id="elem_b" label="{{ mylabel }}" value="{{ myvalue }}"></my-element>
<my-element-c id="elem_c" label="{{ mylabel }}" value="{{ myvalue }}"></my-element>
```

### To

```
<my-element-a id="elem_a" label="{{ mylabel }}"></my-element>  
<my-element-b id="elem_b" label="{{ mylabel }}" value="{{ myvalue }}"></my-element>
<my-element-c id="elem_c" label="{{ mylabel }}" value="{{ myvalue }}"></my-element>
```

### What I tried

```
// 1: 
//Result: elem_b.value becomes null.
this.$.elem_a.removeAttribute('value');

// 2:
//Result: both elem_a.label and elem_a.value loses data binding
//Also inside polymer source I saw this was marked as something which would be
//deprecated
this.$.elem_a.unbindAll();

// 3:
//Result: Works but its dirty
//Create a copy of elem_a with its attributes and values
//except the value
var copy = copyAllExcept(elem_a, 'value');
var parent = this.$.elem_a.parentElement;
copy.removeAttribute('value');    
parent.removeChild(this.$.elem_a);
parent.appendChild(copy);
```

### What I ideally want

```
//Something like this
this.$.elem_a.unbind('value');
```

**Please let me know how to solve this better?**

Note: I use polymer version 0.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymer is using a library called TemplateBinding underneath. This has a public method to unbind a property from a template.

https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/template.html#nodeunbind

I tried to get access to this function in a polymer template but I could not make it work. With some investigation you may find the answer.

Comment: I don't find this API in the Polymer version (0.3.1) which I use. It looks like a new API does exactly what I would need.